# Android : Suggest Strong Password for Android Native App similar to what we have for Google Chrome Browser

Tags: android, kotlin

I am looking for a way to achieve the following in a native android app.
{
This is something that is supported by browsers.
}

The app has a signup page where the user will be asked to enter the user's email and password with a few more fields to be added.
On the password field, I have to show a strong password suggestion dialog (provided by Google) similar to what we get on Chrome Browers if we try to register a new user.
Further same user email and password set can be used by the Login page where these can be pulled back from Google Password Manager.

Till now what I am able to achieve is to store email and password in Google Password Manager.

But the requirement is to show a strong password from Google suggestion and then store it on Google Password Manager.

And still, have to get a way out for fetching the email and password on Login Page.

Comment: what is a strong password? a long string of randon characters. so try to generate it without strange logics.

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
Creating a strong password is easy and can be done. 

I am looking for a way to achieve the following in a native android app : 
This is something that is supported by browsers. If you try to create an account then there will be a suggestion for a strong password and the same can be auto-filled on the login screen for the same page.

Comment: So, confirm that I am understanding this correctly: The user creates an account within your app and you want to suggest a strong password within your app. When the user then signs in through a browser, username and password shall be auto-filled. Is that correct?

Comment: yes. that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, generating a secure password boils down to generating a random string of given length. For such a really simple task, you should avoid including a big third party library or service, because with every third party library you include, you...

- increase the attack surface if anybody wants to hack your app
- make maintainability harder as you need to keep track of library updates and changes in the libraries API
- make your code much harder to understand

So, instead, try to implement such tasks yourself, e.g. like so:

```
fun main() {
    val generatedPassword = generatePassword()
    println("The suggested password is:")
    println(generatedPassword)

    // customize the behaviour like so:
    val customizedPassword = generatePassword(length = 40, CharacterGroup.Numbers, CharacterGroup.UppercaseLetters)
    println("The customized password is:")
    println(customizedPassword)
}

fun generatePassword(length: Int = 15, vararg characterGroups: CharacterGroup = CharacterGroup.values()): String {
    val allCharactersInUse = characterGroups.joinToString("") { it.characters }
    return buildString {
        repeat(length) {
            append(allCharactersInUse.random())
        }
    }
}

enum class CharacterGroup(val characters: String) {
    Numbers("1234567890"),
    UppercaseLetters("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"),
    LowercaseLetters("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"),
    SpecialCharacters("!\"§\$%&/()=?@,;.:-_{[]}\\"),
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Creating a strong password is easy and can be done. I am looking for a way to achieve the following in a native android app : This is something that is supported by browsers. If you try to create an account then there will be a suggestion for a strong password and the same username and password can be auto-filled on the login screen.